# Command prompt is located in the wrong position on the screen

Tags: command-line, tmux

Multiple windows are opened in my tmux. In most windows, the command prompt is located at the bottom of the screen like this:

[image: command prompt at the normal position]

However, in one window, the command prompt got fixed in the middle of the screen. The output of the previous command takes multiple pages, but it only takes half of the screen in the current page:

[image: abnormal position in the middle of the screen]

How can I fix it?

When I enter into the copy mode and press page up, the cursor goes to the middle of the screen in the previous page, which is different from normal behavior of the bottom in other tmux windows.